# Laravel Nova: How can I extend resources and used in custom Nova tool?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

It is possible to extend a resource controller and use it in a Nova tool, so that it can be using all features and customize controllers and routes for e.g. using external API services?

What is the best solution?

Or it is better to build my own tool from scratch?

Answer (score -6):

Nova is just Laravel / PHP so yes you can override it :) (you'll need to meet the interface like defining cards, tools methods etc but before doing it, it's really simple to create your own custom tools / resource tools. Give it a try!